# How to use a variable which is inside a (def) function?

Tags: function

I'm sorry that I'm still a beginner :) And I'm stuck at some point, I hope you could help me.

```
def Test(x):

a = []
if x > 10:
    a.append(2 * x + 1)
    a.append(3 * x + 1)
    a.append(4 * x + 1)
if x == 10:
    a.append(2 * x - 1)
    a.append(3 * x - 1)
    a.append(4 * x - 1)
if x < 10:
    a.append((2 * x) ** 2)
    a.append(((3 ** x)) ** 2)
    a.append((4**x) ** 2)

print(a)

Test(15)
```

if I run this I get no error as you expect. But what I need is the "a" list and it's arguments. For example; if i try:

```
print(a[1])
```

I get following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stockfish/PycharmProjects/ProjectOne/deneme.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(a[1])
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I tried "global" keyword; but either I misused it or it doesn't work, I am not sure.

Yout help is highly appriciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and indent the code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the array from the function to access it outside the function.
In your specific case, it would be:

```
def Test(x):
    a = []
    if x > 10:
        a.append(2 * x + 1)
        a.append(3 * x + 1)
        a.append(4 * x + 1)
    elif x == 10:
        a.append(2 * x - 1)
        a.append(3 * x - 1)
        a.append(4 * x - 1)
    elif x < 10:
        a.append((2 * x) ** 2)
        a.append(((3 ** x)) ** 2)
        a.append((4**x) ** 2)

    print("a = ",a)
    return a

output = Test(15)
print("output[1] = ", output[1])
```

The output would be

```
a = [31, 46, 61]
output[1] =  46
```